# masked input for latitude and longitude with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I create a masked input for longitude and latitude? I need to use the format Degrees/Min/Seconds

```
jQuery(function($){
  $("lat").mask("9999/99/99", { placeholder: "" });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems fine other than the `lat` selector. Presumably that needs to be `#lat`, or `.lat`? https://jsfiddle.net/hksLLev8/

Comment: Thank @RoryMcCrossan, what about incase the degree is two value let say 34